# Default shoulda matchers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shoulda

This is, quite probably, a very rookie question as I'm just getting started with Shoulda.

Can anyone point me to a readable run down of all, or at least the most useful, of Shoulda's "preinstalled" matchers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Is it what you expect](http://rubydoc.info/github/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/master/frames)?

Comment: ...Huh. Yes. I'd found that link, but hadn't managed to navigate it to get [this](http://rubydoc.info/github/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/master/Shoulda/Matchers) and subpages in the RH frame. Forehead-slap.